# Which is the cheapest way to store a (140 chars) string in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am developing a dapp, in which I need to store a string of 140 chars in the blockchain. And I am surprised that the cost of this action is 157 924 gas.

Current prices:
1 gas = 100 Gwei
157 924 x 100 = 15792400 Gwei = 0.0157924 ETH = 66 USD

I have seen several dapps that store information in the blockchain. How can they handle such enormous costs, for relatively small operations? Am I making a mistake in the calculations of the actual cost? Is my contract extremely bad written?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Upload{
    
    mapping(uint8=>string) internal info;

    function setInfo(uint8 id, string calldata Input) external{

        info[id] = Input;
    }

    function getInfo(uint8 id) external view returns (string memory){
        return (info[id]);
    }
}
```

I am pretty new into this, please understand

Comment: `I am developing a dapp, in which I need to store a string of 140 chars in the blockchain. ` Are you sure of this? Sounds like xyproblem https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 3):

You can save a string in the transaction data without saving it on the smart contract context. In this case, the record identifier will be the hash of the transaction. You can always extract transaction data by its hash.

Just create a smart contract with an empty function that does nothing and send transactions with a string to it. You can try using the fallback function - maybe it will be cheaper.

In principle, you can even send a transaction to any account (existing or not) - then there will be no costs for calling a smart contract. In my private test network, in this case, about 25,000 gas turned out.